# Missing assembly reference error in Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I have created an Azure funtion app but on debug mode it is unable to find below mentioned assembly

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

although I have it referenced, In output folder when I navigate to the properties for this particular file it shows file version "5.0.20.51904"

Below is my project file

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 <PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Remove="Scheduler.Core\**" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Scheduler.Core\**" />
<None Remove="Scheduler.Core\**" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="AzureFunctions.Autofac" Version="4.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="SyncFeed_Scheduler.Core\SyncFeed_Scheduler.Core.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<None Update="host.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="local.settings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using .NET 6, but referencing version 5.0.0.0 for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, there might be a mismatch between the version of your project and the dependencies that were added.

I think this could be solved by either explicitly adding a dependency to version 5.0.0.0 of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions`

or

by updating your packages to their latest versions.
For instance: [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/) has a version 6.0.0.0 available.